# Popcorn in latin

Tags: new-latin, borrowing

In Portuguese, popcorn is "Pipoca" from Old Tupi pi'poka pira(skin) pok(burst)
Since latin has borrowed some words(not to mention greek) Could we have it as a borrowed word?
Pipoca is a female noun in Portuguese. It could perfectly be from the first declension.

Comment: For what it's worth, Traupman has *maizium inflatum* for popcorn. I suppose it's plausible pipoca could have entered Portuguese from neo-Latin, which would have got from the Tupi, but I don't see why Portuguese couldn't have borrowed it direct from Old Tupi.

Comment: Traupman? I pass. They say "Pipoca" even in Portugal. Wouldn't it be easier just to latinize a foreign term?

Comment: Random idea, but what if you coined something using _nux_? My thinking is the Romans, not being familiar with corn, might have thought of the kernel as a nut.

Comment: They knew the millet(milium)its grains can be poped. I used to eat it when my father worked on a farm. It's like a tiny popcorn. And a funny fact: the Portuguese word for corn  is "milho" wich came from "milium" perhaps the romans never imagined that if the heat a grian in oil, it could be popped.

Comment: From the Morgan-Owens Neo-Latin Lexicon: "343 corn: popcorn  maizium* inflâtum (HELFER)  ► maizium displôsum  ►► LRL: maizae grana tosta.  EL: pop-corn, maïs éclaté; pop corn; palomitas, alborotos, cabritas; Popcorn" (https://neolatinlexicon.org/adumbratio-old/)

Comment: @Herodotean Your comment is the beginning of great answer.